# LinqToSQL query performance and positioning of .ToList()

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq, entity-framework

I have the following entity framework linq query that executes hundreds of times for different customer Ids and returns potentially hundreds of items:

```
var events = Context.Events.AsNoTracking().Where(l => l.CustomerID == customerId &&
                    l.DateTime >= startDate && l.DateTime <= endDate &&
                    l.EventType != "SomeType" && l.Category.Contains("someString")
                    .OrderBy(l => l.DateTime).ThenBy(l => l.ProductId).ToList();
```

I have been thinking about the performance of this query and have wondered whether adding a ToList earlier in the query would improve performance. I have tried the following and seen about a 20% increase in speed, but am not sure whether this is by chance or not:

```
var events = Context.Events.AsNoTracking().Where(l => l.CustomerID == customerId)
                    .ToList().Where(
                    l.DateTime >= startDate && l.DateTime <= endDate &&
                    l.EventType != "SomeType" && l.Category.Contains("someString")
                    .OrderBy(l => l.DateTime).ThenBy(l => l.ProductId).ToList();
```

I think this is because the ToList brings into memory all of the events with the relevant customer ID, and then the rest of the filtering and ordering occurs in memory in C# rather than in SQL.

Which leads me to think, which operations are faster when executed in C# on in-memory lists as opposed to in linqToSQL?

I've heard that contains() for strings, and orderBy is slow in SQL, are these faster in C# for in-memory lists?

Is there a guide for which operations I should perform in memory and which I should perform in SQL?

Comment: You can check what SQL is generated in both approaches and see if the SQL query itself is optimal or not

Comment: It's generally better to let SQLServer handle these sorts of things. In your case you may find performance improves if you create the necessary index. Try your initial query but having created an index on Event of CustomerId, DateTime, ProductId

Comment: Be careful though when doing string operations against SQL server from LINQ, look at the underlying SQL that was produced to see the function that was used.